# Find an example to show that $\int\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j\neq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int f_j$

Tags: measure-theory

> > Consider functions $f_j\in\mathcal{L}^1, j\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j$ be convergent and in $\mathcal{L}^1$. Find an example in order to show that
> >     $$
> > \int\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j\neq\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int f_j.
> > $$

Do you have an idea resp. help for me how to find such an example?

Comment: If each $f_j \ge 0$ these would be equal as a consequence of the monotone convergence theorem, so an alternating series is a good place to start.

Comment: Can you again explain why $f_j\geq 0$ is not good? \\ A convergent alternating series is $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{j+1}\frac{1}{j}=\ln 2$, so maybe $f_j(x):=(-1)^{j+1}\frac{1}{j}$?

Comment: @math12 $f_j \ge 0$ is not good because if we define $g_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} f_j$ then sequence $\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is monotone increasing and positive so we can apply monotone convergence theorem to conclude $$\begin{align}\int \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} f_j &= \int \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j = \int \lim_{n\to \infty} g_n \\ &\overset{\text{MKT}}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int g_n =\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j \\ &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \int f_j = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int f_j,\end{align}$$ so $$\int\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}f_j = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\int f_j.$$

Comment: @math12 Of course, we here $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \sum_{j=1}^{n} f_j = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^{n} \int f_j$$ swapped  $\sum$ and $\int$ because sum is **finite**. And in your question you should say in which space we are working (probably in $\mathbb{R}$, but...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_j=\frac{1}{j}1_{[0,j]}-\frac{1}{j-1}1_{[0,j-1]}$ for $j\geq 2$ and $f_1=1_{[0,1]}$, where $1_A(x)$ is 0 when $x\notin A$ and is 1 when $x\in A$. We have that $\sum_{j}^nf_j=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$. By taking limit, we get that $\sum_{j}^\infty f_j=0$, but $\sum_{k=1}^n\int_\mathbb{R}f_k=1$ and so converges to 1.

Comment: But $\int f_1 = 1$.

Comment: Yup you're right! I'm fixing it!

Comment: Thanks for that answer. How did you get that idea?

Comment: I first thought of it by finding functions $g_n$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}g_n$ exists and $\lim_{n}\int g_n\neq\int\lim g_n$. I thought that the easiest example would be when $g_n\to 0$ but the integrals don't go to 0, like for example $g_n=\frac{1}{n}1_{[0,n]}$. By playing around a bit we can write $g_n$ as a sum of $f_k$, and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

A classic example of a sequence $a_{mn}$ for which $\sum_m \sum_n a_{mn} \neq \sum_n \sum_m a_{mn}$ is given by the entries of the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&0&\cdots\\-1&1&0&0&\cdots\\0&-1&1&0&\cdots\\0&0&-1&1&\cdots\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots\end{array}\right).$$
Now just let $f_{n}(x) = a_{\lfloor x\rfloor n}$.

Answer (score 0):

The "double or nothing" martingale works like this.  On space $[0,1]$ let
$$
f_0 = 1
$$
and for $n \ge 1$,
$$
f_n = 2^{n-1}(1_{(0,2^{-n}]}-1_{(2^{-n},2^{1-n}]})
$$
So that $\int\sum f_n = 0$ but $\sum \int f_n = 1$.

These $f_n$ are the martingale differences.  The martingale itself is
$$
S_N = \sum_{n=0}^N f_n = 2^N\;1_{(0,2^{-N}]}
$$